# Continuously looping UIScrollViews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm working on developing a CoverFlow type UIScrollView implementation quite similar to this
https://github.com/thefaj/OpenFlow by Alex Fajkowski. I'm developing it more as a learning exercise as I keep finding the requirement to do similar things for menus/selections in my user interaces.

Alex's OpenFlow example is great but I'm wondering how to make it loop continuously, instead of scrolling A to B as the UIScrollView seems to do.

Is it possible, or a good idea, to loop views within a UIScrollView for a continuous 'flow' of images/items somehow or is there a better approach than using a UIScrollView for this?

I'm thinking that without the UIScrollView the smooth scrolling and inertia etc might be hard to re-create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the number of images to a big number in the afcoverflow and load dynamically. this isnt make the coverflow infinite but it does what you want

Comment: I'm not looking to use the adcoverflow example as such, more using it as a guide to get me in the right direction as pretty new to iOS development. I want to make a looping cover flow type view, it will come in very useful for alsorts of UIs, and will 'scratch a few' of my itches :)